# Voltage drop over MOSFET controlled by microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, buck-boost

I made the circuit below to power a microcontroller and a load from one power source.

But looking at the voltage drop between drain and source of the IRLZ44N MOSFET, instead of 12 V I got only 3.1 V when the MOSFET is opened by ATtiny85's 4.5 V signal.

What am I doing wrong that lets 3.1 V drop instead of 12 V between drain and source?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have discovered the ideality of placing a switch on the high side clashing against the the real world operating requirements of the more common N-channel MOSFET (as opposed to P-channel). Think about what the source pin voltage does as current flows through the load and recall that the gate-source voltage  (NOT the gate voltage or gate-gnd voltage) is what controls the MOSFET. MOSFET cannot see GND and does not care what GND is.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Gate voltage limits Source to "-" voltage.
Hm, Source to "-" voltage acts like variable Zener diod, that can be tuned by Gate voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What do I do wrong to get 3.1 volts instead 12 volts between Drain and
> Source ?*

You are operating the IRLZ44N MOSFET as a source follower and, when this happens, the source voltage can never exceed the gate voltage and usually, it's a volt or two lower (as you see). Try operating the MOSFET as a common source with the load connected between drain and +12 volts.

> *I got only 3.1 volts when mosfet is opened by ATtiny85 4.5 volts
> signal.*

Best not use the term "opened" because this is electrical engineering and an open circuit means "no connection". If you were on a hydraulics site then you would call a valve open that allowed fluid to pass. Not in EE!

If you want to use a term use "activate" or "deactivate".

Comment: It works ( placing Load between + and Drain ).
Thank you.
About terms "open"/"close" in transistor context, I agree it is ambiguous, but instead "activate" or "deactivate", for me "turn on"/"turn off" will be more intuitive.

Comment: I think placing Load after Source and adjusting Gate voltage acts like variable Zener diode. So we can limit voltage passing through Load by changing Gate voltage.

Comment: The source voltage will be the gate voltage minus 1 or 2 volts but, it won't be easily definable i.e. you can't rely on it to be a voltage regulator like a zener diode.

Comment: Yes, 1 or 2 volts is quiet big, and temperature of mosfet can chage it.
But atleast Source voltage can't be greater than Gate voltage, so 1 or 2 volts can be compensated,
just increase Gate voltage on that 1 or 2 volts.

Comment: Or use an op-amp to automatically compensate just like a linear voltage regulator.